# How can I tell systemd to run a shell script 1 second before the end of every minute

Tags: bash, systemd

I know how to run a job every minute or every 59 seconds, but what I need here is for the script to run 1 second before the end of every minute i.e:

```
7:05:59  (7am 5 minutes 59 seconds)
7:06:59  (7am 6 minutes 59 seconds)
```

And so on.

Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to run multiple instances every minute regardless of how many jobs already running? if not, should job killed out of time, or should be waited until finished?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with `systemd` I assume you are using a systemd timer. You can use something like this:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:*:59
AccuracySec=100ms
```

Be sure to check `systemd.timer(5)` about the `AccuracySec=` option, because there are some caveats. Notably, setting accuracy too high might affect system performance.